# Allow Public IP to connect via WebSockets

Tags: node.js, networking, websocket, router, portforwarding

I tried to creating a chat with nodejs ws (einaros),this is my code:

Server:

```
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;
var wss = new WebSocketServer({ port: 80 });
wss.on('connection', function(ws) {
    console.log('connecting count:' + wss.clients.length);
});
```

Client:

```
var hostname = location.hostname;
var port = 80;
var url = 'ws://'+hostname+':'+port+'/';
window.WebSocket = window.WebSocket || window.MozWebSocket;
var w = new WebSocket(url);
```

when I test with my computer or some other computers who connect with my router, it works well. However, other clients who visit via Internet cannot make the connection. Of course, they use the public IP, like 218.xxx.xxx.xxx, not 192.168.xxx.xxx.

I wonder how to solve this problem.

Thank you for you answer. But, it may be not the NAT problem. For example, My public IP is 218.100.50.50,and My private Ip is 192.168.1.1. When a connection comes from outside my network and visits 218.100.50.50:80, the router will redirect it to 192.168.1.1:80. There's a web page which can be visited in this way, but still cannot make the connection to my websocket server. This problem really confuses me much.

Answer (score 4):

Sitting behind router with IPv4 leads to problems for routing actual traffic to right direction (computer behind router).

You need to Forward port 80 in router settings to your computer IP. Additionally I would recommend set in router settings preferred IP for your computer so after restart it is more likely not to change local IP address (otherwise can happen).

After those changes, you can even try to connect using Public IP from your own computer, and if it will work - then it should work from external computers.
Additionally check firewall settings to make sure it does not blocks any external traffic to port 80.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is called NAT: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation

When a connection comes from outside your network (that is, against your public IP), the router doesn't know who's going to receive that connection. Imagine there are 3 PCs and 2 smartphones connected to your router, which one is going to "answer"? Well, what you have to do is tell the router: "dear router, when my friends try to connect on port 80, redirect them to device 192.168.1.37 and port 80 (for example)".
And if you don't want to reconfigure your router again and again to update 192.168.1.37 (because of DHCP random IP assignation) then tell your router to assign the same IP to your PC always (static ip).

So, configure a "static IP" for your PC, and create a port forwarding rule for port 80 to redirect traffic to your server. You can search "server behind router configuration" for more details, there are thousands of tutorials.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. However, when I set the NAT, it still doesn't work. For example, My public IP is 218.100.50.50,and My private Ip is 192.168.1.1. When a connection comes from outside my network and visits 218.100.50.50:80, the router will redirect it to 192.168.1.1:80. There's a web page which can be visited in this way, but still cannot make the connection to my websocket server. This problem really confuses me much.

Comment: hi nagi, did you find any solution, im stuck with same problem